# Find points on $n$-dimensional grid within hypersphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms

Given an infinite $n$-dimensional grid, and an arbitrary hypersphere with center **c** and radius $r$, how can one efficiently generate all points of this n-dimensional grid that are within the hypersphere?

Example on a $2d$ grid:

[image]

Points that lie within the hypersphere are green, points outside are red. (Please excuse the messy grid)

One possibility is to enumerate all points within a hypercube of side length $r$, and reject points that aren't within the hypersphere. However, this approach quickly loses efficiency as the ratio between points in the hypersphere and hypercube decreases as dimensionality $n$ increases.

I'm considering a method that finds the closest point, then the $2nd$ closest point, etc. until a point outside the hypersphere is reached, but the details elude me.

Note: For my particular problem, the grid has arbitrary distance between points (ex. $0.5, 1.0, 1.5, ...)$, but I suspect any method that works on a regular grid should generalize easily.

Edit: I've implemented both Paul Sinclair and Anton Sherwood's methods. In my tests (with very similar implementations to minimize other factors), Sinclair's method is faster when dimensionality of the problem is $> 3.$ Although Sinclair's method has greater constant factors due to the use of a square root, it does not require checking points outside the hypersphere. As dimensionality increases, the ratio of points found inside the hypersphere to outside decreases for Sharwood's method. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to order your dimensions, and limit inside loops based on the values outside:

   `for(x1 = ceiling(-r); x1<= r; x1++) 
      r2 = sqrt(r^2 - x1^2)
      for(x2 = ceiling(-r2); x2 <= r2; x2++)
         ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your “closest point” idea is on the right track.  Start with the closest (n-1)-hyperplane.  Within it, start with the closest (n-2)-plane ... These are much easier to order than the grid points themselves!

Before you begin each plane of any dimension, see whether it intersects the sphere at all.  If not, no further planes of that dimension will either; step to the next plane one dimension up.

This approach requires no square roots, and the number of rejections is at worst proportional to the surface of the hypersphere rather than the volume of (hypercube-hypersphere).

Comment: Let's see if I understand this. To get each (n-k)-hyperplane I compare the k-th component of the center to the k-th component of the grid. By locking a component, and leaving the others variable, I have a hyperplane. Once every component is determined, I have a point on the grid. However, I'm not sure how to efficiently determine if the hyperplane intersects the hypersphere.

Comment: The minimum distance of the hyperplane to the centre is the distance of the point you get by setting the remaining free coordinates to those of the centre (i.e., setting delta in those dimensions to zero).  Is that distance (squared) less than the radius (squared)?

Comment: I managed to successfully implement this method, but it doesn't appear to scale well to higher dimensions. If I understand this correctly, checking if a hyperplane with n fixed coordinates intersects the hypersphere requires n subtraction and n multiplication operations. **v** . **v**, where **v** = **p**' - **c**'. **p**' is the vector of fixed coordinates and **c**' is the vector of corresponding center coordinates.

Comment: Each hyperplane's squared distance is (∆x_i)^2 – which can be precomputed – added to the squared distance found in the next outer loop, so you needn't compute v•v from scratch as often as you suggest.

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right. This is a significant optimization. However, in my tests, this method still does not scale as well to higher dimensions, due to checking a point outside the hypersphere before continuing to the next hyperplane, which Paul Sinclair's method does not require. In my tests, this method is faster for 3 and fewer dimensions.